# Bitmap Orientation Changes

Tags: android, android-camera

I have made a Custom Camera app and I am showing my image in an imageview after the camera Click. But here I am facing a problem that the image I captured always set in  changed orientation.

i.e If I capture the pic while taking my camera as Portrait it don't set the image as Portrait, It changes the orientation.

Here is the camera click code :-

```
@Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            //here we write the code for saving the picture onto the sdCard


            File pictureFileDir = getDir();

            //to check whether directory exists or not!!
            if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

                //Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image.");
                Toast.makeText(Irant_Custom_cameraApplication.this, "Can't create directory to save image.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;

            }

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            photo_file="Picture_"+date+".jpg";

            photo_FileName = pictureFileDir.getPath()+File.separator+photo_file;

            picture_file = new File(photo_FileName);

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(picture_file);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();

                String imgpath = photo_file;
                System.out.println("Path for the image*********************"+photo_file);
                SignupDetails.imagePath=imgpath;

            }


            catch (Exception e) {

                Log.d("Image save error :", e.getMessage());    
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not always implemented the same for each device, some rotate automatically, others don't. I think the best approach is to look at the [EXIF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) data of the file. That's your best bet.